# Class A initialisation within class B containing pointer to class A

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, initialization

I wish for a class A to contain some data, and class B will contain a pointer to that data. I am providing access to the data through a function returning a reference to the data object A. If I create an object B then i can access the object A, however if create a pointer to B then the equivalent operation produces a segmentation fault.  Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    A(const int pInt) {mInt = pInt;}
    void print() {std::cout << mInt << std::endl;}
private:
    int mInt; //some data
};

class B {
public:
   B() {mP1 = new A(1);} //initialise to 1
   ~B() {delete mP1;}
   A& access() {return *mP1;} //return reference to the data

private:
    A* mP1; //pointer to some data
};

int main() {
    B vB;
    vB.access().print(); //this works.

    B *vBptr;
    vBptr->access().print(); //Segmentation fault!

    std::vector<B*> vVec;
    vVec.resize(1);
    vVec[0]->access().print(); //Segmentation fault!
}
```

I guess when creating B *vBptr then a B object is not getting initialised?
How then could I create a vector of pointers to B objects that are automatically initialised?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues in your program

```
B *vBptr;
```

Your pointer has not been initialized, and though its a pointer of type B but is not pointing to a valid object of type B. Change it to

```
B *vBptr = new B();

vVec.resize(1);
```

Here resizing does not allocate the storage for each of the elements of the vector. You can initialize the elements with the actual object by supplying the initialization to the resize method of the vector

```
vVec.resize(1,new B());
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could do this. +1

Comment: Cool, what about deallocating the memory when the array goes out of scope? Is that handled automatically?

Comment: Just to warn that if `resize(1, new B());` is changed to `resize(2, new B())` there would be two elements in the vector pointing to the same instance of `B`.

Comment: @RobSimpson: No it won't. After all its a vector of Pointers and not objects.

Comment: @hmjd cool, I didn't know that either. Then... I'm guessing this isn't a safe solution...

Comment: @hmjd: Off-course its just the same instance but if you are initialing the vector while resizing this will work.

Comment: @Abhijit, I don't understand your comment? Even if you are initialising the vector you could still end up with more than one element referring to the same instance of `B`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, IMO this is quite fragile, though it does work for this case.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize the pointer:

```
B *vBptr = new B;
vBptr->access().print();
```

Same applies for your vector - you'll have to iterate through the elements and initialize them.

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < vVec.size() ; i++ )
   vVec[i] = new B;
```

**Note that you'll have to manually free the memory**:

```
delete vBptr;
```

and

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < vVec.size() ; i++ )
   delete vVec[i];
```

not to run into memory leaks.

Comment: How do I create a vector of B* that is initialised?

Comment: @RobSimpson I don't think you can automatically. But iterating through it and initializing the components is enough.

Comment: Is there any way to default construct an object automatically when you create a pointer to that object?

Comment: @RobSimpson if you had a vector of objects, they would be constructed automatically. **But** you can use a wrapper class, and have values of that, kind of like a smart pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to set your pointer to something:

```
B *vBptr;          // bad -- uninitialized 
B *vBptr = new B;  // proper
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers a pointer variable does not automatically allocate memory for it, so you need to manually allocate and deallocate the memory like this:

```
B vB;
vB.access().print(); //this works.

B *vBptr = new B;//allocate memory for vBptr
vBptr->access().print();
delete vBptr;//clean up of vBptr
std::vector<B*> vVec;
vVec.push_back(new B);
vVec[0]->access().print(); 
delete vVec[0];
```

However I would advise against managing memory with raw pointers, since it is way to easy to get memory leaks and errors. E.g. the code above leaks memory if `vBptr->access().print()` throws an exception. Your `B` class has a violation of the rule of three (default copy constructor/assignment op while manually managing resources). So if you copy a `B` object horrible things will happen (double free and access to already deleted memory to be exact).

Therefore I would suggest you use some sort of smart pointers. If you use c++11 you can use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`, otherwise their is `std::tr1::shared_ptr`. If your compiler doesn't have tr1, boost also has `boost:shared_ptr`. Then your code would look like the following:

```
class B {
public:
   B():mP1(new A(1)) {} //initialise to 1
   ~B() {} //no extra managing necessary
   A& access() {return *mP1;} //return reference to the data

private:
    std::shared_ptr<A> mP1; //pointer to some data
};

int main() {
    B vB;
    vB.access().print(); //this works.

    std::shared_ptr<B> vBptr(new B);
    vBptr->access().print();

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B> > vVec;
    vVec.push_back(std::shared_ptr<B>(new B));
    vVec[0]->access().print(); 
}
```

If you need minimal overhead and are using c++11 `std::unique_ptr` is your friend, otherwise iirc boost has `boost::unique_ptr`. Just stay away from `std::auto_ptr`. There really is little reason to manage your memory manually unless you like the added complexity/potential for bugs or your code is extremely performance sensitive (and uses extremely efficient custom allocators).

Answer (score 0):

```
B *vBptr;
vBptr->access().print(); //Segmentation fault!
```

Well, of course; you created a variable that stores a pointer to a B object, but you didn't actually make it point at a B object. (hint: see the code you wrote for the B class where you make the B's `A* mP1` point at something?)

```
std::vector<B*> vVec;
vVec.resize(1);
vVec[0]->access().print(); //Segmentation fault!
```

Well, of course; you created a vector of pointers to B objects, and then you resized the vector to add one element; that element is a default-constructed pointer-to-B. For pointer types, the default construction is a null pointer, so again you aren't pointing at any actual B object.

Your problem has nothing to do with any of the A or B implementation.

> How then could I create a vector of pointers to B objects

Why do you think you want to do this? What's wrong with just making a vector of B objects?

Comment: B is an abstract base class in my implementation.

Comment: Strange that you don't seem to have `virtual` anywhere, then.

Comment: Don't want to over-complicate the real problem.

Comment: Anyway, if the reason for the pointers is to allow for polymorphism (storing a heterogeneous collection of things derived from B), then you really really should be looking into either some form of smart pointer, or into using `boost::ptr_vector` or similar. Managing the pointers yourself is a headache and a half, and an unproductive use of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
B vB;
vB.access().print();

B *vBptr = &vB; // or B *vBptr = new B;
vBptr->access().print();

std::vector<B*> vVec;
vVec.push_back(&vB);  // vVec.push_back(new B);
vVec[0]->access().print();
```

However, is there a need to write B NOT this way?

```
class B {
 public:
  //   B() {}
  //   ~B() {}
  A& access() {return a;}

private:
   A a;};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who contributed. The following is the implementation that I have now adopted, i.e using boost::shared_ptr:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "boost/smart_ptr.hpp"

class A {
public:
    A(const int pInt) {mInt = pInt;}
    void print() const {std::cout << mInt << std::endl;}
    void set(const int pInt) {mInt = pInt;}
private:
    int mInt; //some data
};

class B {
public:
    B() {}  //leave A pointer as null
    ~B() { } //delete handled by shared_ptr
    A& access() {return *mP1;} //return reference to the data
    boost::shared_ptr<A>& access_A_ptr() {return mP1;} //return the pointer for assignment

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<A> mP1;
};

int main() {

    std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<A> > vVecA; //data to be shared
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        boost::shared_ptr<A> vAptr(new A(i));
        vVecA.push_back(vAptr);
        vVecA[i]->print();
    }

    vVecA[2]->set(123);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vVecA.size(); i++) {
        vVecA[i]->print(); //changes to the underlying objects are reflected
    }

    boost::shared_ptr<B> vBptr(new B); //make an empty B
    vBptr->access_A_ptr() = vVecA[2]; //assignment of shared pointer

    vBptr->access().print();

    std::cout << "use count of vVecA[1] = " << vVecA[1].use_count() << std::endl; // = 1
    std::cout << "use count of vVecA[2] = " << vVecA[2].use_count() << std::endl; // = 2

    std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<B> > vVecB;

    //vVecB.resize(vVecA.size(), boost::shared_ptr<B> (new B) ); //resize and init to a SINGLE B object, NO!!!

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vVecA.size(); i++) {
        vVecB.push_back(boost::shared_ptr<B> (new B)); //filling array with separate empty Bs
        vVecB[i]->access_A_ptr() = vVecA[i];
        vVecB[i]->access().print(); // = 0,1,123,3,4
    }

    vVecA[2]->set(2); //changes to A objects reflected in the B objects

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vVecB.size(); i++) {
        vVecB[i]->access().print(); // = 0,1,2,3,4
    }

    std::cout << "use count of vVecA[1] = " << vVecA[1].use_count() << std::endl; // = 2
    std::cout << "use count of vVecA[2] = " << vVecA[2].use_count() << std::endl; // = 3

}
```

This has effectively become an exercise in shared pointers. Comments are still very welcome on any aspect, however.

Thank you!